# launch4j: "The process cannot access the file..."

Tags: java, executable, launch4j

I just upgraded to Win 7, and now my launch4j setup isn't working anymore.

Clues?

Using the launch file below, I get these errors:

```
 [exec] launch4j: Compiling resources
 [exec] launch4j: Linking
 [exec] launch4j: Wrapping
 [exec] launch4j: H:\Documents\QueryAnalyzerFaker\QueryAnalyzerFaker\.\batchexport.exe (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
 [exec] launch4j: java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\Documents\QueryAnalyzerFaker\QueryAnalyzerFaker\.\batchexport.exe (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
```

Here's the launch configuration

```
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>console</headerType>
  <jar>.\batchexport.jar</jar>
  <outfile>.\batchexport.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <customProcName>false</customProcName>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>.\1326449361_table_money.ico</icon>
  <jre>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6</path>
    <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>jreOnly</jdkPreference>
    <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by some interference between the synchronization service for the destination drive (network drive) and launch4j.

I resolved it by building on the local c: drive, then adding an Ant target for copying the output to the desired folder on the network drive.